# Attach Image to Email Send through Web API 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, nativescript, email-attachments

I have mobile App with data entry form with Image option. Now when I click on submit all the data should bind in body and Image should attach to email which I am sending through web api. I am able to send email without image. How to attach mobile device's image to web api which sends Email?

### Picture Capture code.

```
exports.onCapture = function(args)
  { 
var dialogs = require("ui/dialogs");
dialogs.action({
  message: "Select Option to Attach Image",
  cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
  actions: ["Camera", "Gallary"]
}).then(function (result) {
  console.log("Dialog result: " + result); 
  if(result == "Camera"){
      //Do action1
      console.log("Camera selected");
      if(imagecontainer.imageSource!=null)
      {
          imagecontainer.imageSource=null;
      }

camera.takePicture({
width: 200, height: 200, keepAspectRatio: false, saveToGallery: true
})   
.then(function (imageAsset) {
    console.log("Result is an image asset instance"); 

    filepath = fs.path.join(fs.knownFolders.documents().path, "img_" + (new Date().getTime() / 1000) + ".jpg");

    imageAsset.getImageAsync(image => {

    imagecontainer.imageSource = imageSource.fromNativeSource(image);

   (imagecontainer.imageSource).saveToFile(filepath, uiEnums.ImageFormat.jpeg);
    console .log("image source:"+image);
    });
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log("Error -> " + err.message);
});
  }else if(result == "Gallary"){
      if(imagecontainer.imageSource!=null)
      {
          imagecontainer.imageSource=null;
      }
      //Do action2
      var items;
      var imagepicker = require("nativescript-imagepicker");
      var context = imagepicker.create({
          mode: "single"
      });
      context.authorize()
          .then(function() {
              return context.present();
          })
          .then(function(selection) {
            filepath = fs.path.join(fs.knownFolders.documents().path, "img_" + (new Date().getTime() / 1000) + ".jpg");
              selection.forEach(function(selected) {
                selected.getImage({ maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: 200, aspectRatio: 'fill' })

                .then((imageSourceS) => {
                    imagecontainer.imageSource = imageSourceS;

                    imageSourceS.saveToFile(filepath, uiEnums.ImageFormat.jpeg);
                });

                console.log("pic selected");
              });
          }).catch(function (e) {
          console.log(e);
      });
  }
  console.log("file path;;;;;;:"+filepath);
 });

};
```

### WebAPI which sends email

```
   public async Task<string> SendEMail(string recipient,string subject, string message)
    {
        string isMessageSent = "";
        try
        {

            //Intialise Parameters  
            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("10.10.200.98");
            client.Port = 25;
            client.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Properties.Settings.Default.EmailHost, Properties.Settings.Default.EmailHostPassword);
            client.EnableSsl = false;
            client.Credentials = credentials;

            var mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(Properties.Settings.Default.EmailHost, recipient);
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.Body = message;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;




            //System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;  
            //attachment = new Attachment(@"C:\Users\XXX\XXX\XXX.jpg");---->this should be image from filepath of above   .js file
            //mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);  
            client.Send(mail);

            isMessageSent = "Sent";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            isMessageSent = ex.ToString();
        }
        return isMessageSent;

    }
```

Comment: Why are you returning a string from this code instead of just allowing the exception to propagate and handling that at the point where you can do something about it?

Comment: @mason right now if exception occurs I am able to know as I am setting it ---> isMessageSent = ex.ToString();

There's no exception so far as mail service working perfectly but i don't know how can I attach image which i get in my mobile app. once I found out that i will try to catch exception rather than returning it into string format.

Comment: I'm not really concerned about your image thing right now. What I'm trying to point out is that there is no need to return a string indicated the message was sent. You can tell that the message was sent if there was no exception. And if there is an exception, you should allow it to bubble up to the location where you can actually take some alternate action. Don't shove it in a string, you lose all context at that point.

Comment: @mason Okay got it, I will remove that, thanks for explaination.